# How do I make a PHP CORS request?

Tags: php, curl, cors

I'm trying to use PHP Curl to make a request to our API site. At the moment, I'm trying to make a simple request

The API site has a directory which returns JSON formatted data. The script is shown below:\

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

$arr['id'] = '001';
$arr['desc'] = 'Simple JSON output';

$json = json_encode($arr);

echo $json;
?>
```

If I access the API site (api/test_json) from my browser, I see the json data:
[image]

I have a PHP script on another domain trying to get the JSON data:

```
<?php
$url = "http://ourapi.com/test_json/";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($str);
?>
```

But as I run, I get a return of bool(false). Did I miss anything on my codes?

Comment: Why are you setting ssl options when the url does not use ssl? By the way, if you call the api from php you don't need the CORS header, you only need that if you want to call the api directly from javascript.

Comment: I can remove the SSL. Unfortunately, JavaScript is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side calls are not subject of Cross-Origin-Request policy. The problem is somewhere in availability of the API. Is there any authenticaion required? Probably when you request it from browser you have a session cookie.

Simplify you code just to `file_get_contents("http://ourapi.com/test_json/");` enable all errors display and see is it gives any errors.

Comment: I see, problem is that the webhost from where I'm calling the API does not allow file_get_contents() to be called. Hopefully, I can still make a server side CORS request.

Comment: If file_get_contents() with URLs is restricted, isn't it possible to that CURL is also disabled? Are you running this code on something like Google AppEngine?

Comment: Some web hosts restricts use of file_get_contents(), but allows CURL. The code is running on our web host