# Issues with PHP Curl - no response on echo

Tags: php, curl, mime

Folks.

Hope someone can help me with the following, I'm trying to pass form data using php curl to an API.

HTML CODE:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Texting API</h2>

<form action="connectapi.php" method="post">
  <label for="country">Country:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="country" name="country" placeholder="e.g. Germany"><br>

  <label for="currency_code">Currency Code:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="currency_code" name="currency_code" placeholder="e.g. EUR"><br>

  <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="e.g. johndoe@gmail.com"><br>

  <label for="first_name">First Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="e.g. John"><br>

  <label for="last_name">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="e.g. Smith"><br>

  <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="e.g. +4915903910271"><br>

  <label for="gmt_timezone">Timezone (GMT):</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="gmt_timezone" name="gmt_timezone" placeholder="02:00 for Germany"><br> 
  <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder=""><br>
  <br>
  <input id="postSubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send!">
</form>

<p>Note that the form itself is not visible.</p>

<p>Also note that the default width of text input fields is 20 characters.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE:-

```
<?php

$country = $_POST['country'];
$currency_code = $_POST['currency_code'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$gmt_timezone = $_POST['gmt_timezone'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$lang = "en";
$campaign_id = "5f901a2XXXXX";

$mergeall = 'country=' . $country . '&currency_code=' . $currency_code . '&email=' . $email . '&first_name=' . $first_name . '&last_name=' . $last_name . '&phone=' . $phone . '&gmt_timezone=' . $gmt_timezone . '&password=' . $password . '&lang=' . $lang . '&campaign_id=' . $campaign_id;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "XXXXXX/api/users/XXXX/create-client?api_key=DrvgCdyhZXXXXXIn3ZNOsfu1udUGtk1603704804844",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $mergeall,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

So, when I'm trying to submit the form I end up with a "Locked" response and the following in console:-

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response ***WEB
> HOST*** with MIME type text/html. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
> details.

Comment: have you tried googling the error message you get? [First result](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers) is really self explanatory on the issue you have

Comment: Yes, I did but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Usually `cUrl` does not have CORS restriction. It seems that API itself is invalidating your request. If so, then you can just ask them to whitelist your request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a PHP CORS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150073/how-do-i-make-a-php-cors-request)

Comment: @Justinas I've actually spoke to the provider, and it seems there are no issues with sending this request. We've also tested on postman, still nothing.

Comment: Maybe check your server config. Maybe you can't access your own backend?

Comment: @Justinas I've added the headers to the php file...still same error. How do I check my server configurations?

Comment: @Justinas that's a CORB issue not strictly CORS imho. The remote site refuses to be embedded/called by another domain.